# Compiling with swift-numerics failed with error in ApproximateEquality.swift

Tags: swift

I import a library 'Chart' as project into my project and compile, the result is failed due to an error related to a dependency package 'swift-numerics'.

The error indicates 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context' in 2 locations in ApproximateEquality.swift of RealModule of the package, where both imply something wrong like ' .\magnitude' as below.

the package comes along with officially download demo project.
Xcode: 11.3.1
Swift: 5

```swift
    public func isApproximatelyEqual(
        to other: Self,
        relativeTolerance: Magnitude = Magnitude.ulpOfOne.squareRoot(),
        norm: (Self) -> Magnitude = \.magnitude
    ) -> Bool
```

and here

```swift
    public func isApproximatelyEqual( 
        to other: Self,
        absoluteTolerance: Magnitude,
        relativeTolerance: Magnitude = 0
    ) -> Bool {
        self.isApproximatelyEqual(
        to: other,
        absoluteTolerance: absoluteTolerance,
        relativeTolerance: relativeTolerance,
        norm: \.magnitude
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to Xcode 13, Swift 5.5. You cannot possibly expect these packages to work with your super-outdated version of Xcode.

Comment: It is shame that my MacBook has hard driver issues like S.M.A.R.T whose OS can not be updated, so as Xcode...I will figure out if any older versions of Charts project can be pulled from GitHub. Thanks.

Comment: Hardware issues are off topic. This is simply a matter of getting your code to compile.